# Is 'friendly reminder' a positive word? What is an alternative with a friendly undertone?

Tags: politeness

I send reminders to my customers all the time. And, I hesitate to use the word 'friendly reminder'. I interpret it as a soft reminders before aggressive reminders. It brings up an image of a thug asking me to payup before his next visit, This might be because of the movies I watch.

So, what would be a substitute for 'friendly reminder' with a polite undertone.

Comment: I’m afraid this is not really a very good question for the StackExchange format, because it does not lead to a clear, best answer. For example, just because I might think that a *gentle reminder* sounds less like you’re leaning on someone than a *friendly reminder* might, others might have just the opposite reaction, and there is no way to judge one above the other. This is also extremely culturally-biased, so what is considered eminently polite and non-threatening in say New Jersey might seem like brutal enforcement by a crime syndicate in say Japan. :)

Comment: Whenever you have to add a modifier to say you're being friendly or honest or sincere, people know very well that you're lying. It's like you mother saying, _Johnny, I'm asking you nicely to clean up your room_. It's really an order. I never send "friendly reminders". I just outright ask when I can expect to be paid for the editing I did 3 months earlier. First, though, I ask whether they received my email & say I know that email deliveries here are sometimes problematic & that it may have gone into their spam folder. Collection agencies send "friendly reminders". I don't.

Comment: May be off-topic. I suggest that you avoid the qualifier altogether. The friendliness **should** manifest in the phrasing of the reminder itself.

Comment: BillFranke and Kris'comments give excellent advice.  If you decide to use "reminder", though, ***"just a reminder"*** is not modified with a word like "friendly", but has a little less formality than saying "this is a reminder".

Comment: A 'gentle reminder', perhaps?